# visual studio 2017 Structure Visualizer missing

Tags: visual-studio

I'm not sure when it disappeared but my structure visualizer is not displaying. I tried unchecking the box in options, Show structure guide lines, and rechecking. I also tried resetting all settings to default, changed the color for the guidelines, rebooting and they are still missing. 
I do have Reshaper installed so I suspended that to see if there is a difference and they still won't show.
The only other thing I did recently was install other templates such as Xamarin for mobile development but I'm not sure it is related of if that is when they disappeared.
Does anyone have any other ideas short of reinstalling VS? I have 15.4.5.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/10/11/productivity-structure-visualizer-ctrl-click-to-go-to-definition/. Seems to only available in the version of VS2017 that came out yesterday. Do you have this version?

Comment: No, I mean the default feature included with VS2017, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-in-visual-studio. I do see that article was from yesterday like you said. I know of other people who have the previous version and they have the guidelines.

Comment: I have the dotted lines but not the tool tips that it mentions. Maybe that is the update you get with 15.5. Might be worth upgrading to this version anyway.

Comment: I don't have the dotted lines so that is the issue I am seeing.